# VUE detect key press and duplicate keys detected error

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i'm creating app, where i'm detecting key down and send the key to external server.

Generaly all works, but after few key down i'm starting to receiving error"

```
[Vue warn]: Duplicate keys detected: '3'. This may cause an update error.
```

Communicate with pushed key is still correct send to server, but in console i have mess.

Do you know what is all about, and how to resolve the problem?

My method is:

```
keymonitor(event) {
  if (event.key.length === 1) {
    this.keyDown = {
      cmd: 'keyboard',
      key: event.key,
    }
  } else if (
    event.key === 'Enter'
      || event.key === 'Tab'
      || event.key === 'PageUp'
      || event.key === 'PageDown'
      || event.key === 'End'
      || event.key === 'Home'
      || event.key === 'ArrowLeft'
      || event.key === 'ArrowUp'
      || event.key === 'ArrowRight'
      || event.key === 'ArrowDown'
      || event.key === 'Backspace'
      || event.key === 'Delete'
      || event.key === 'Escape'
  ) {
    this.keyDown = {
      cmd: 'keyboardSpecial',
      key: event.key,
    }
    // event.preventDefault();
  }
  console.log(this.keyDown)
  this.sendMessage(this.keyDown)
},
```

and i run it with:

```
 window.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  this.keymonitor(e)
})
```

the loop v-for is:

```
<app-timeline-item
          v-for="item in array"
          :key="item.id"
          v-bind:style="{display: timelineDisplay}">
        <b-button
            v-ripple.400="'rgba(113, 102, 240, 0.15)'"
            variant="outline-dark"
            class="btn-icon rounded-circle"
            disabled
            style="margin-top: -13px; margin-left: -18px; float: left; margin-right: 15px;"
        >
          <feather-icon v-if="item.name === 'mouseEvent'" icon="MousePointerIcon" />
          <feather-icon v-if="item.name === 'scrollToEvent'" icon="MoreVerticalIcon" />
          <feather-icon v-if="item.name === 'selectEvent'" icon="ListIcon" />
        </b-button>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-sm-row flex-column mb-sm-0 mb-1">
          <h6>{{ item.name }}</h6>
        </div>
        <b-media no-body>
          <div class="demo-inline-spacing">
            <b-col lg="6" style="margin: 0 auto;">
              <b-media-aside class="mr-1 mediathumbnail">
                <b-img
                    height="64"
                />
                <div :id=item.id style="text-align: center; margin-top: 8px">
                </div>
              </b-media-aside>
            </b-col>
            <b-col lg="4">
              <b-media-body class="my-auto" lg="6">
                <p v-if="item.x">X: {{ item.x }}</p>
                <p v-if="item.y">X: {{ item.y }}</p>
              </b-media-body>
            </b-col>
          </div>
        </b-media>
      </app-timeline-item>
```

Comment: do you have a `v-for` in template?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim This would 100% be his issue, not the event listener. I have added an answer elaborating on the need for unique keys

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue with `v-for`, not with your event listener.

Vue is complaining that some of the items in your `v-for` loops have a duplicate key - a key with value `3`.

This is an issue because Vue uses keys to manage node updates of the list items. Effectively, Vue uses the keys to compute a diff between two node trees to see which components have changed and how.

If two or more elements in the same list have the same key, Vue will not be able to uniquely track changes in state/component order.

This can lead to conflicts and rendering errors when you start moving/updating elements in the list.

Edit:

Afterlooking at your update, I can see you're setting your key using  `:key="item.id"`

This error is because two or more of your items have the same ID - `3`.

I recommend being careful with the index approach as suggested by the other answer. Using the index in this way can lead to issues with VueJS tracking the components if they are re-ordered.

If there is no way to sort/re-order this list then this is okay, but otherwise it's not advised.

Comment: ok, but i'm using v-for only once - i've updated code

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've two or more ids that equal to 3, so you should make the `key` attribute value unique as follows :

```
<app-timeline-item
          v-for="(item,index) in array"
          :key="item.id+index" 
         ....
```